# Rails 6 : Enum within a class

Tags: enums, rails-activerecord, helper, ruby-on-rails-6

I am struggling to make work my Catalog with enum within a class, from this tuto : https://naturaily.com/blog/ruby-on-rails-enum.

My models :

```
**app/models/catalog.rb**
class Catalog < ApplicationRecord
  include ArrayToEnumHash
  enum state: array_to_enum_hash(CatalogState::STATES)

  def state
    @state ||= CatalogState.new(read_attribute(:state))
  end
end
```

```
**app/models/catalog_state.rb**
class CatalogState
  STATES = %w(incoming in_progress finished).freeze

  def initialize(state)
    @state = state
  end

  # what you need here
end
```

```
**app/concerns/array_to_enum_hash.rb**
module ArrayToEnumHash
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  def array_to_enum_hash(array)
    result = {}
    v = array.to_enum
    w = array.map {|v| v.to_sym }.to_enum
    loop do
      result[w.next] = v.next
    end
    result
  end
end
```

```
**db/schema.rb**
create_enum :catalog_state, [
    "incoming",
    "in_progress",
    "finished",
  ]

create_table "catalogs", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.enum "state", enum_name: "catalog_state"
    t.index ["state"], name: "index_catalogs_on_state"
  end
```

My Catalog seems fine :

```
#<Catalog:0x00007fe87dbfb810
 id: 3,
 created_at: Thu, 02 Jul 2020 16:52:36 UTC +00:00,
 updated_at: Fri, 03 Jul 2020 19:51:26 UTC +00:00,
 status: "unset",
 auction_type: "internet",
 state: "in_progress">
```

However, on my console, ActiveRecord doesn't build the enum shortcuts :

```
[5] pry(main)> c.state
=> "in_progress"
[6] pry(main)> c.in_progress?
NoMethodError: undefined method `in_progress?' for #<Catalog:0x00007fe87dbfb810>
from /Users/pierre/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activemodel-6.0.3.2/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:432:in `method_missing'
```

WTF ?

Comment: I must ask where do `create_enum` and `t.enum` come from?

Comment: My aim here is to create the direct access methods. to go further than the integer & array setup : instead of the array ["incoming", "in_progress", "finished"] , I set up the hash {:incoming=>"incoming", :in_progress=>"in_progress", :finished=>"finished"}, so that I can directly access to : ```my_instance.incoming? => false ```,  ```my_instance.incoming!```. So the question is about the helper setup, which seems to be right but doesn't work.

Comment: But you don't need to do that by yourself. That's handled by Rails :D, take a look to the [docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.0.0/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html); "_... the bang and predicate methods along with the associated scopes are now prefixed and/or suffixed accordingly_".

Comment: I used the gem 'activerecord-postgres_enum', with ```create_enum``` and ```t.enum``` helpers. So all this part of the tuto is no use ?  good to know :) I appreciate your help, I thought it could be a good thing to have a separate class to access the different values, even with their own methods, like the Voivodeship Class in the tuto[https://naturaily.com/blog/ruby-on-rails-enum]. I agree array on activerecord can handle a lot.

Comment: If the use you're going to give to that enum column needs something ActiveRecord can not provide you, you can use the gem. Otherwise, the example I gave in the answer must be enough to start with it.

Comment: You can anyway do, it's not directly attached to the use of the gem. Although, I must mention that if you're going to hardcode all those "voivodeship"s, why not store them in your database? The approach might have pros, but also cons. Food for thought.

Comment: Yes thanx Sebastian, I'll explore these open possibilities after some more practice of the enum :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need that much in order to add an "enum" column in your catalogs table.

```
class CreateCatalogs < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :catalogs do |t|
      t.string "status"
      t.string "auction_type"
      t.integer "state"
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

An enum column can be represented with an `integer` data type column, there `t.integer "state"`.

An in order to set the enum values, you can just call the constant defined in `CatalogState`:

```
class Catalog < ApplicationRecord
  enum state: CatalogState::STATES
end
```

The values will be `["incoming", "in_progress", "finished"]`, otherwise, using the helper method in the concern it'll be like `{:incoming=>"incoming", :in_progress=>"in_progress", :finished=>"finished"}`, and there, Rails has no way to infer the integer value they represent.

After that you can try it:

```
catalog = Catalog.new(id: 3, created_at: 'Thu, 02 Jul 2020 16:52:36 UTC +00:00', updated_at: 'Fri, 03 Jul 2020 19:51:26 UTC +00:00', status: 'unset', auction_type: 'internet', state: 'in_progress')
catalog.valid? # true
catalog.save
Catalog.last
# Catalog Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "catalogs".* FROM "catalogs" ORDER BY "catalogs"."id" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
# => #<Catalog:0x00007fc4d9448f90 id: 3, status: "unset", auction_type: "internet", state: "in_progress", created_at: Thu, 02 Jul 2020 16:52:36 UTC +00:00, updated_at: Fri, 03 Jul 2020 19:51:26 UTC +00:00>
Catalog.last.in_progress?
# Catalog Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "catalogs".* FROM "catalogs" ORDER BY "catalogs"."id" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
# => true
```